# Roll back to libc6-amd64 using a live cd and chroot on ssd with GPT filesystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, ubuntu-14.04, chroot

I was attempting to follow a steam guide to install a dedicated game server. See my original post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665501/no-gui-in-ubuntu-14-04-2-after-attempting-to-install-ark-server?noredirect=1#comment961088_665501).

Basically I really messed up. I attempted to roll back but when it downgraded my network adapter I was kicked from the system (really wish I would have used screen) and the roll back failed half way.

I'm now attempting to mount my filesystem via a live cd to make repairs using [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109182/libraries-crash-after-installing-experimental-version-of-libc6) as a guide.

I can not get my drive to mount in the /mnt directory using the mount command because it is a GPT filesystem. I can however click on the hard drive icon in the sidebar and get it to mount under:

```
/media/ubuntu/uuid/
```

When I mount it this way then chroot I get error messages for every command I run:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libapt-pkg.so.4.12: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
ls: error while loading shared libraries: libattr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory
```

Does this have something to do with the mount point being at:

```
/media/ubuntu/uuid/
```

as opposed to:

```
/mnt
```

I updated the commands as follows for my alternate mount point chroot:

```
mount -o bind /proc /media/ubuntu/uuid/proc
mount -o bind /dev /media/ubuntu/uuid/dev
mount -o bind /dev/pts /media/ubuntu/uuid/dev/pts
mount -o bind /sys /media/ubuntu/uuid/sys
```

Then I updated my chroot command to:

chroot /media/ubuntu/uuid/ /bin/bash

This chroot appears to work, but again no commands work.

Any advice on how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: How many partitions does your disk have? Was it all just one big partition or were there others besides /?

Comment: Just the one, best I can remember. If I run parted on sda1 its only showing a single partition that is 98mb yet the drive is a 256gb SSD. It raises questions.